# How to find all matching keys and values of one object in array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I need a code which would loop through an array of objects and check if keys and values match with ones in a separate object, and then push object that contains all keys and values in a new array, so for a specific case:

```
var arr = [{name: 'john', lastname: 'roberts', children: 3},
           {name: 'john', lastname: 'green', children: null}, 
           {name: 'steve', lastname: 'baker', children: 3}];

var obj = {name: 'john', children: 3};
```

result would be:

```
arr2 = [{name: 'john', lastname: 'roberts', children: 3}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

expanding @Psidom version

```js
var arr = [{name: 'john', lastname: 'roberts', children: 3},
           {name: 'john', lastname: 'green', children: null}, 
           {name: 'steve', lastname: 'baker', children: 3}];

var obj = {name: 'john', children: 3};

console.log(
  arr.filter(x => Object.keys(obj).every( k => x[k] == obj[k]))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on the Array:

```js
var arr = [{name: 'john', lastname: 'roberts', children: 3},
           {name: 'john', lastname: 'green', children: null}, 
           {name: 'steve', lastname: 'baker', children: 3}];

var obj = {name: 'john', children: 3};

console.log(
  arr.filter(x => x.name === obj.name && x.children === obj.children)
);
```

Comment: But what if I don't know keys or have another array of objects with different key names?

Comment: Can you give an example? Do the keys in the `obj` always exist in the keys of objects in the array?

Comment: Yes, in first example we had name, children keys in another we'd have age, height, weight or whatever (in both array and obj). So I can't use key names, I rather need a universal solution for both cases.

Comment: I think @JarekKulikowski 's answer is what you need.